# unable to add text in the horizontal rule

Tags: css, html

this is my css file

```
.venue-hr-text {
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
/*  border: 0;*/
  font-family: 'GreatVibesRegular';
  text-align: center;
  height: 1.5em;
  opacity: .5;
  &:before {
    content: '';

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  &:after {
    content: attr(data-content);
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-color: #fcfcfa;
  }
}
```

this is my html code

```
<hr class="venue-hr-text" data-content = "just three steps away">
```

I have also added an online link for the font I am using which is greatvibesregular...
still, my code is not working

the hr is also not shown on the web page

Comment: because you cannot put text inside a hr tag . It is basically a line, also the hr is being shown but lts almost transparent, https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=QCA4uHM5fa

Comment: we can https://codepen.io/scottzirkel/pen/yNxNME
visit this link

Comment: The code you posted should work fine. Have you tried refreshing the cache or checking to see if other styles are overriding it?

Comment: yes i did but it's not working...

Comment: @juhi Can you see the text in this fiddle (this is the code you posted) --> https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/6ugph9oy/ --> just give `:before`a background-color and your line will show

Comment: does it work? @juhi

Comment: no but i tried the next code section and the text is showing below the hr

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal rules don't take text nodes.

You can use a P tag, then set the display to flex and use both pseudo-elements in order to create the "hr" besides it.

Something like this:

```
<p class="hr">
  Something, Something, Darkside
</p>
```

css:

```
p.hr{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center
}

p.hr::before, p.hr::after{
  content:"";
  flex:1;
  background-color:red;
  height:1px;
}
```

Compared to other methods, this one allows text to be selected.

[JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/facundocorradini/hLzwuzep/)

Comment: only the text is coming with this

Comment: rlly? did you checked the linked JSFiddle?

Comment: just tested it, it works perfectly fine in every browser but IE, probably because of one of the infinite number of flexbox bugs on IE.

Answer (score -2):

Just Change your css according to your needs. Also the code you were referencing was of sass not css so &:before and &:after cannot be used under the class like it was in sass.

```
.venue-hr-text {
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 1.5em;
  opacity: .5;
}
.venue-hr-text::before {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(left, transparent, black, transparent);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
  }
 .venue-hr-text::after {
    content:  attr(data-content);
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: black;
    background-color: #fcfcfa;
  }
```

[js fiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_cobold/wdjr32vs/)

Comment: with this content is coming below the hr